# Problema na estrutura condicional

Tags: algoritmo, lógica, condição, visualg, portugol

Estou estudando algoritmos e lógica de programação, e um dos exercícios é usar a estrutura condicional no contexto de IMC (Índice de Massa Corporal). O programa deve calcular o IMC com base na massa e na altura, e informar se a pessoa está ou não no seu peso ideal. A linguagem é Portugol e o ambiente é o Visualg. O problema, é que ele está dizendo que o peso é ideal mesmo quando o IMC está abaixo do desejável. Eu já verifiquei a condição várias vezes, mas não estou conseguindo identificar o erro. Poderiam me ajudar, por favor?

Segue o código:

```
Algoritmo "CalculoIMC"

Var

   massa, altura, IMC: Real

Inicio

      Escreval("*********************************************************")

      Escreval("Calculo de IMC")

      Escreval("*********************************************************")

      Escreval("")

      Escreva("Informe sua massa corporal (kg): ")

      Leia(massa)

      Escreva("Informe sua altura (m): ")

      Leia(altura)

      IMC <- massa/(altura^2)

      Escreval("")

      Escreva("Seu IMC e igual a ", IMC:3:1, ". ") //Variável imc apresentada com 3 casas totais, sendo uma decimal.

      Se ((IMC >= 18.5) e (IMC < 25)) entao

         Escreval("Voce esta no seu peso ideal. Parabens!")

      senao

           Escreval ("Voce NAO esta no seu peso ideal.")

      FimSe

Fimalgoritmo
```

Os resultados:

**1. Abaixo do peso**

```
Início da execução
*********************************************************
Calculo de IMC
*********************************************************

Informe sua massa corporal (kg): 40,0000000000
Informe sua altura (m): 2,0000000000

Seu IMC e igual a 10.0. Voce esta no seu peso ideal. Parabens!

Fim da execução.
```

**2. Ideal**

```
Início da execução
*********************************************************
Calculo de IMC
*********************************************************

Informe sua massa corporal (kg): 80,0000000000
Informe sua altura (m): 2,0000000000

Seu IMC e igual a 20.0. Voce esta no seu peso ideal. Parabens!

Fim da execução.
```

**3. Acima do Peso**

```
Início da execução
*********************************************************
Calculo de IMC
*********************************************************
Informe sua massa corporal (kg): 150,0000000000
Informe sua altura (m): 2,0000000000

Seu IMC e igual a 37.5. Voce NAO esta no seu peso ideal.

Fim da execução.
```

Comment: Fiz os testes e nos 3 casos o código funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Obrigada, talvez esteja dando algum bug no programa aqui então. Eu tinha testado várias vezes e dava isso. Mas vou ver então se dá certo reiniciando tudo ou fazendo outro programa. Muito obrigada.

Comment: Realmente, o problema ocorreu com o programa! Obrigada.